# c variadic functions, same arguments, different formats

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm having a problem with `va_` methods, and I couldn't find an example (or didn't figure out what the keywords are). The problem is, I need to use the same args for different formats, but the compiler gives me:

> incorrect usage of va_start

error. The code I'm trying is something like this:

```
void vSaveNecessaryFields(EnumA eFormat, ...)
{
    va_list xArgs, xArgs2;
    const char *fmt1 = NULL, *fmt2 = NULL;
    char caString[100] = {0};

    fmt1 = cpGetDbFormat(eFormat);
    fmt2 = cpGetPrinterFormat(eFormat);

    va_start(xArgs1, fmt1);
    va_copy(xArgs2, xArgs1);
    vsnprintf(caString, sizeof(caString), fmt1, xArgs1);

    vSaveToDb(caString);

    va_start(xArgs2, fmt2);
    vsnprintf(caString, sizeof(caString), fmt2, xArgs2);
    vPrintFormatted(caString);
    va_end(xArgs2);
    va_end(xArgs1);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `va_start(xArgs1, fmt1)` --> `va_start(xArgs1, eFormat)`

Comment: trying it now. who downvoted this and why?

Comment: it worked. write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `va_start` should be the `eFormat` argument.  Furthermore, the `va_list` is declared as `xArgs` but you use `xArgs1`, which causes a syntax error.

```
void vSaveNecessaryFields(EnumA eFormat, ...) {
    va_list xArgs, xArgs2;
    const char *fmt1 = NULL, *fmt2 = NULL;
    char caString[100] = {0};

    fmt1 = cpGetDbFormat(eFormat);
    fmt2 = cpGetPrinterFormat(eFormat);

    va_start(xArgs, eFormat);
    vsnprintf(caString, sizeof(caString), fmt1, xArgs);
    va_end(xArgs);

    vSaveToDb(caString);

    va_start(xArgs2, eFormat);
    vsnprintf(caString, sizeof(caString), fmt2, xArgs2);
    vPrintFormatted(caString);
    va_end(xArgs2);
}
```

Comment: `xArgs -> xArgs1` was a typo of mine when I simplified the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call va_end, then call va_start a second time after you have closed the parameter block.